# How do you find the smallest value reachable from a node in a DAG in linear time?

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, topological-sort

I am trying to follow 3.25(a) from http://seed.ucsd.edu/mediawiki/images/4/43/Sol3.pdf

I understand you have to do topological sort on a graph first. But I don't understand how they get the min in cost[w]. If there are 2 outgoing edges from u how do you account for them using this algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially dynamic programming. When there are multiple outgoing nodes, you pick the min at each stage. That gives the min overall when you finally reach your starting point. Draw an example and step through it.

Comment: So if I have something like A=4, B=4, C=5 and  C<--A-->B where I start at A, the topsort would be <A, C, B>.

So you would do cost[B], then cost[C], then cost[A]. How do you pick the min at A, is that an extra traversal?

Comment: I may have misinterpreted the reverse topological order. If I start at A then I can step through it linearly. Is this correct?

Comment: Let's pick a slightly more complicated example: A -> B, A -> C, B -> D, C -> E, D -> E. A = 4, B = 4, C = 5, D = 2, E = 3. We have an extra variable, x_n = min reachable from node x, which is initially undefined. Working backwards through the top sort, x_E = 3; x_D = min(2,x_E) = min(2,3) = 2; x_C = min(5,x_E) = min (5,3) = 3; x_B = min (4,x_D) = min (4,2) = 2; finally x_A = min(4,x_B,x_C) = min(4,2,3) = 2. As a bonus we get the path to the minimum value by working forwards again: just follow the 2's. If there's more than one branch leading to a 2, it doesn't matter.